# Making histogram of object attribute of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, histogram

I am making histogram from a dataset but observed that `hist()` works only for numerical data values. While I have some object type attributes in my dataframe, for example: Name, gender (possible values: male, female) etc.

I want to plot histogram for gender attribute of my dataset. How is that possible with `.hist()` or any other mechanism?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter

mydataFrame.hist(column = "Gender")
```

"Gender" is an object type attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
mydataFrame.gender.value_counts().plot(kind='bar');
```

`value_counts()` will make a series with the values of gender in the index, and the count as the values.